# Ошибка 1005 Can't create table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Пытаюсь создать 2 таблицы с каскадным удалением и обновлением:

```
create table Details(
        code_detail mediumint not null auto_increment,
        type_detail enum('buy', 'own'),
        name_detail varchar(20) default 'detail',
        unit_detail varchar(20),
        price_detail int check (price_detail>0),
        primary key (code_detail)
        ) engine=InnoDB;

create table Availability(
        number_stock int not null,
        code_detail int,
        unit_detail varchar(20),
        quantity_detail int default '0',
        last_date date,
        primary key(number_stock, code_detail),
        key code_detail(code_detail),
        constraint detail_ibfk_1
        foreign key (code_detail)
        references Details(code_detail)
        on update cascade
        on delete cascade
        )engine=InnoDB;
```

С первой проблем нет, однако при создании второй (`Availability`) появляется ошибка:

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'Mounth.Availabity' (erno: 150)

Благодаря активному гуглению выяснил, что ошибка с внешними ключами, но до конца понять не могу, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в несовпадении типов PK и FK:

```
Details.code_detail: mediumint

Availability.code_detail: int
```